# Elasticsearch nested query and order by "hits"

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, nosql

Using Elasticsearch, I'm trying to search nested data and return the documents with the most "hits."

Relevant Example Data

```
POST myrecipes/recipe
{
    "title": "Potato Salad",
    "ingredients": [
        {"name":"potato"},
        {"name":"mayonaise"},
        {"name":"mustard"},
        {"name":"bacon"},
        {"name":"onion"},
        {"name":"parsley"}  
    ]
}

POST myrecipes/recipe
{
    "title": "Seared Scallops",
    "ingredients": [
        {"name":"scallops"},
        {"name":"butter"},
        {"name":"bacon"}
    ]
}

POST myrecipes/recipe
{
    "title": "Tuna melt",
    "ingredients": [
        {"name":"tuna"},
        {"name":"onion"},
        {"name":"butter"},
        {"name":"bacon"},
        {"name":"mayonaise"},
        {"name":"lettuce"},
        {"name":"tomato"},
        {"name":"bread"}
    ]
}
```

My Index

```
PUT myrecipes
{
  "mappings": {
    "recipe": {
      "properties": {
        "ingredients": {
          "type": "nested",
          "include_in_parent": true,
          "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "string",
                "fields": {
                    "untouched": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    }
                }              
            }            
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My Search:

```
POST  myrecipes/recipe/_search
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "ingredients",
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "should": [
                {
                  "match": {
                    "ingredients.name": {
                      "query": "bacon"
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "match": {
                    "ingredients.name": {
                      "query": "butter"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
    }
}
```

The query returns

"Tuna melt", "Potato Salad", "Seared Scallops"

I'm hoping for:

"Seared Scallops", "Tuna melt", "Potato Salad"

Since there are two "hits" on "Seared scallops" and "Tuna Melt" (bacon and butter), and only one "hit" on "Potato Salad" (bacon).

Comment: With your example I get the following scores: ["Seared Scallops", 0.7864545], ["Tuna melt", 0.7864545], ["Potato Salad", 0.6678343]

Comment: That's weird. I just set up this example again and received the following: 

"Tuna melt" 0.7419715, "Potato Salad" 0.49069843, "Seared Scallops" 0.45526436

Comment: Indeed, the first test was with Elasticsearch 1.5.2. With Elasticsearch 2.4.0 the score was ["Tuna melt", 0.7419715], ["Seared Scallops", 0.7282377], ["Potato Salad", 0.54902744]